# Tumblr tag visit statistics

Tags: google-analytics, tags, ranking, visitors, tumblr

Is there a way to get the visit number of different tags? I already set up a Google Analytics account to work with my tumblr blog, but I guess I reach more people through tags than site visits. I just wonder exactly how many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GA go to:

`Traffic Sources > Sources > Referrals > tumblr.com`

And you'll find a list of all the tag referrals you've received.